# SearchView in fragment Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, searchview

I have a toolbar into fragment and i want to add searchView for this toolbar

I have this:

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_principal, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.buscar);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            try {
                ArrayList<Producto> listaFiltrada = filter(list,newText);
                adapterProductos.setFilter(listaFiltrada);
            }catch (Exception r) {
                r.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            adapterProductos.setFilter(list);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

and this item menu:

```
<item android:title="Buscar"
    android:id="@+id/buscar"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:actionViewClass= "android:support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    />
```

But i have a null pointer...

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: jaimeperezpedraza.org.tienda, PID: 15971
>                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference

I think I'm not catching searchView well...

help?

Comment: `View getActionView (MenuItem item)` is deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionView(android.view.MenuItem)

Comment: Oh...thanks i go to search other mettod

Comment: @VeneetReddy - it was only deprecated in version 26.0.0, which is still in alpha. You still need to use `MenuItemCompat.getActionView` if you're using an earlier version of the Support Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NullPointerException` is due to the `searchView` being null. This is because your XML has `app:actionViewClass="android:support.v7.widget.SearchView"` - note the `:` in the middle of the class name.

It should instead be `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`:

```
<item android:title="Buscar"
  android:id="@+id/buscar"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
  app:actionViewClass= "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
  />
```